# Access / process (nested) objects, arrays in JSON using AJAX JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have a (nested) data structure containing objects and arrays. How can I extract the information, i.e. access a specific or multiple values (or keys) like 1, 105 ,1055?

For example:

```
[{"1":{"url":"http:\/\/web.com\/","catname":"HOBBIES"}},
{"105":{"parent":"1","url":"http:\/\/web.com\/","catname": "TRUCKS"}},
{"1055":{"parent":"105","url":"http:\/\/web.com\/","catname":"TIRES"}} ]
```

Code is :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var formURL = 'http://web.com/ajax.php?store=photo&action=jsoncategories';
        $.getJSON( formURL, function(json) {
        $.each(json[0], function(i, object) {
              $.each(object, function(property, value) {
              console.log(property + "=" + value);
              });
           });
        });
});
```

json[0] is traversing data for key 1. What should replace json[0] to extract all data keys of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is traversing using JavaScript over your elements. I assume that data was loaded and and traversing starts in your code as follows:

```
var json = [{"1":{"url":"http:\/\/web.com\/","catname":"HOBBIES"}},
{"105":{"parent":"1","url":"http:\/\/web.com\/","catname": "TRUCKS"}},
{"1055":{"parent":"105","url":"http:\/\/web.com\/","catname":"TIRES"}} ];



for(var i=0, json_len=json.length; i< json_len; i+=1)
{
    var j = json[i]; // Here you are accessing to the item of Array using index of item.
    for(var k in j)
    {
       var d=j[k]; //Here you are accessing to the object using key pair.
       for(var l in d)
           console.log( k, ':', l, ':', d[l]);
    }
}
```

You can see sample code execution in [**JSFIDDLY**](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/rF8Km/).

If you have long json array this approach better. Because your `json` variable is Array and traversing among elements of array should be done using `for` loop. Your items of array is objects so they should be traversed using `for ... in`. This is best approach to keep in mind. Because `for loop` is faster than `each`. Here is [comparison](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-each-vs-for-loop) in jsperf. If you have question feel free to leave comment here.

Comment: thanx mate for the answer.. but it does not return value(see jsfiddle as well) for k and l while i am replacing console.log to alert( k, ':', l, ':', d[l]);  Anything i am missing..pleas let me know

Comment: Did you using Chrome? If so, did you open console window? In case if you cannot use console look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/rF8Km/2/).

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a " before TRUCK.
Also, try using `console.log(property + "=" + value);`  instead of alert().

```
$.each(json, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val, function(index, value){
         console.log(value);
    });
});
```

or maybe like so:

```
$.each(json, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val, function(key, val) {
        console.log(val.url);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx for the changes.. this works fine upto traversing. My actual question is:  What should replace json[0] to extract all data keys of array

Comment: json[0] will only return the 1st value in the array, in this case it is an object.

Comment: fixed and answered the question.